# how would iterate through and compare the students class and the class schedule class and if they are the same then display them on the html page

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

```
                     @*If Student attends the same class ID as the Class Schedule*@
        @foreach (var item in Model.Where(p => p.Class_Schedule.ClassID.Equals(Model.Any(p => p.Student.Enrollments.Any(p => p.ClassID)))))
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AttendanceID)
                </td>
```

This is my html file that i added to my MVC application, wanted to make an if statement that will check if the student ID is enrolled on the same class as class as the class schedule ID. If it is it will display his details and if he isnt it will ignore him and iterate on. I am getting an error on `(p=>p.ClassID)` the error is cannot implicitly turn type `int` into `bool`

Comment: Can you post your model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an error because .ANY returns boolean not an int like ClassID (i.e. Int <> Bool).

What you're trying to accomplish may be easier to do in two separate loops like so (you may have to align to your models but just the general concept):

```
@foreach (var classItem in Model.Class_Schedule)
   { 
        var classId = classItem.ClassID;

        <tr><td>@* classItem.Whatever your class name is *@ </td></tr>

        @foreach(var student in Model.Student.Enrollments.Where(e => e.ClassID == classId))
            {
              <tr>
                 <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(student => student.AttendanceID)
                 </td>
               </tr>
            }

    }
```

Comment: I used your logic and applied the following  foreach (var classItem in Model.Select(p => p.Class_Schedule))
                {
                    var classId = classItem.ClassID;

                <tr><td>@classItem.ClassID </td></tr>
                    foreach (var item in Model.Where(p => p.Class_Schedule.ClassID.Equals(classId)))

                    {

Comment: Then i got an exception so i added this "@if (Model.Select(p => p.Class_Schedule) != null)" but im getting the exception "value cannot be null. Parameter name "source""

Comment: Can you post your models and classes?

Comment: I figured it out, I put the if null statement before the other iff statement